# Q: Microphone is not working in SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am creating a bot like an alexa.

I am using `SpeechRecognition` module to create my project.

There is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):
    '''It speak out the audio to the user'''
    engine.say(audio)
    print(f"Bot: {audio}")
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    '''It wish the user through datetime module'''
    hour = int(datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning!")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")
    else:
        speak("Good Evening!")

    speak("I am AI bot. Please tell me how can I help you.")

def takeCommand():
    '''It takes command from the users's microphone'''
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening . . .")
        audio = r.listen(source)
 
    try:
        print("Recoginizing . . .")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en_in')
        print(f"You: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        speak("Say that again please")
        return "None"
    return query



if __name__ == '__main__':
    wishMe()
    takeCommand()
```

When I run my code, It does not hear my voice.

Please answer me as fast as you can. But don't change the code too much.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Bluetooth headphone try use anything else like built in microphone, because these modules don't work properly with Bluetooth devices

Comment: No, I am not using bluetooth

Comment: Sorry I don't know 

Comment: It's okay. Anyone else know answer??